# New Login Page in ngx-admin with own auth service

Tags: angular, ngx-admin, nebular

Response of my login API is

> {"access_token":"Q4_OXFjv00VMCuKi1wyvXfCsEzIMUAGOi7V_aQ5UDGJo0jjE8zBOLnVc8w1qP2Jv3YggVGp9DSwX0ppLfwKksXPTJTtGUKwshDouRDnxk3IRr8R8xynhDKCx0lZNzd0jU8ksOK9i9ukSb2VhmsP0N8Z0HOjSJViij-MdNI2bdoQK2TETK6eDN_T4eHw37Ki53NoJk6SNivqko-kZVvkvczgSCNur4XqSVxHiv3hNQ8k-ivbuaBylG1tErRPnoYlDxLULA95_iVW68Gj6J76RvzIBaJXIw371NpUJKfdl7b4X9mRaDTaITJoeyfxXw-DoAJZypx62i1joF88VowfH0A","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"Code":206,"Message":"Sucess","AccountId":12,"GroupId":11}

My auth token is not decode-able as its not JWT. I needed the response to be saved in a service or in the cookies.
I wanted to use style or theme of nebular's login page but unable to do so.

API's params are:

```
{
    username: "email@email.com",
    password: "1234567",
    grant_type: "password:,
    appid: 123
}
```

I made a new component for login, but I unable to copy css and html. When I don't use nb-layout it constantly showing loader(spinner).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could save it in localstorage and use the iss to determine if the token is valid. getting the iss is simple and using the split('.') function, getting your payload in the second index "[1]" and you can decode this using window.atob() function. but since it isn't a jwt, i'm not really sure what your question is.

Comment: sorry I wrote some thing wrong antually em asking about styling a component as login page of ngx-admin's or Nebular's there are two issue 
- spinner is not hiding
- where to get its css

Comment: the token thing is just to explain the situation that I can't use default page provided

Comment: you could also right click the element on the page and inspect it to see it's class and then customise it yourself in your custom css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nebular login page and your own service for login and registration. I would say this is perfect tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toRmWFzB6-E&t=323s

Comment: Video unavailable....